# Revealing text in a shiny document

Tags: r, shiny

In an interactive document, is it possible to use a block of shiny code to hide/reveal markdown?

A simple example of what I'd like to do is:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
What is $2+2$?

```{r reveal, echo=FALSE}
actionButton("button", "Reveal solution")
#Try (unsuccessfully) to comment out rest of document
renderUI(HTML(ifelse(input$button, "", ("<!--"))))
```

The answer is $4$.
````

In my real use case the question and answer would be long and both involve some shared randomly generated R variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that should work for You:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
What is $2+2$?

```{r reveal, echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)
actionButton("button", "Reveal solution")
#Try (unsuccessfully) to comment out rest of document
renderText({if(input$button == 0) {NULL
}else{
print("The answer is 4")}})
```
````

if i understood correctly You wanted to get the solution of `2 + 2` after pressing the `actionButton`, therefore i have used the `if...else...` statement saying that if value of the `actionButton == 0`, it should return `NULL`, else text: `The answer is 4` should be printed.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a workable solution. The problem is that in my real application the answer might be very long rather than a single sentence. So I'd like to keep it as plain markdown rather than turn it into a string variable within R.